# How to map query for iBATIS with parameterized column in select clause?

Tags: java, sql, orm, persistence, ibatis

I want to have a method that finds a certain value from a column of a particular table in the database, where the name of the column is passed in as a parameter. So the Java method would have the following signature:

```
public Integer getFoo(String column) throws DataAccessException;
```

My attempted mapping for this query is the following:

```
<select id="getFoo" parameterClass="java.lang.String" resultClass="java.lang.Integer">
    select min($column$) from daily_statistics where $column$ &gt; 0
</select>
```

This fails in an interesting way. If I call this method once, it works. But if I call it twice with different column names, the second call fails with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in com/company/project/dao/ibatis/maps/FooBar.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a result map.  
--- Check the getSomething-AutoResultMap.  
--- Check the result mapping for the 'MIN(FIRST_COLUMN)' property.  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:181)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryForObject(GeneralStatement.java:100)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:561)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:536)
at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:97)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$1.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:273)
at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:209)
... 21 more
```

Note that 'FIRST_COLUMN' represents the name of the first column, even though the error occurs on the second call, never on the first call.

I have discovered that the following mapping will not give errors, even when called multiple times:

```
<select id="getFoo" parameterClass="java.lang.String" resultClass="java.lang.Integer">
    select min(ANY_COLUMN) from daily_statistics where $column$ &gt; 0
</select>
```

So it seems that the problem is related to the use of a parametrized column in the select clause.

Comment: Use an alias in the you SQL query. Thats should solve the problem of mapping the result back to java.

Comment: That worked. If you want to give an answer, I'll accept it. If you don't, I'll answer myself by the end of the day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an alias in the SQL query. That should solve the problem of mapping the result back to java.