# Parametrized column for Ibatis Query works first time, fails on second call

Tags: sql, ibatis

I have a problem similar (or exactly the same) to what I found here:
[How to map query for iBATIS with parameterized column in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139525/how-to-map-query-for-ibatis-with-parameterized-column-in-select-clause/21193950?noredirect=1#comment31913042_21193950)
But the answer given there seems to not work for me.
I have the following:

```
<typeAlias alias="resultado" type="java.lang.String"/>
<typeAlias alias="parametro" type="java.util.Map"/>

<select id="getValorVariable" resultClass="resultado" parameterClass="parametro">
    SELECT $campo$ FROM $tabla$
    WHERE $campoClave$ = #valorClave#
</select>
```

The first time it executes the select, it works. $campo$ has the value 'CIF'. The second time it runs, it should have the value 'FECHA' but it keeps 'CIF'. In the function calling the select, I check the map and its values, and it has the correct ones.

Any idea? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You're facing this problem because iBatis pre-compiles the entire query except for the param values. Those are dynamically added when the query runs. So, the first time your query gets run, it gets pre-compiled with the column names in your `SELECT` statement.

Add

```
remapResults="true"
```

to your `<select>` tag.

It should read like this:

```
<select id="getValorVariable" resultClass="resultado" parameterClass="parametro" remapResults="true">
```

Further, in your `<sqlMapConfig>` add this to the `<settings>` tag:

```
statementCachingEnabled="false"
```

Comment: Oops.. just saw that this was from Jan 17!

Comment: I have (now had!!) this same problem.  Thanks so much for the answer!!!!